# Entity Framework complex relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have class **A** which **inherits from class B**, at the same time class A has **many instances of B**. Class **B contains class A** property as a reference.

I'm looking for the best way to map this relationship using EF Codefirst.

Comment: I can hardly imagine this relationship. What's A and B in your real code?

Comment: I think you should consider tearing B apart into two classes, because I can;t see any logical way to use this kind of relationship

Comment: Are you thinking of a Category, Subcategory kind of a scenario where subcategory is an instance of Category and Category can have many sub categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is **NOT** inherited from B. They have a few common properties like this:

```
class ABCommon
{
    //common properties here
}

class B : ABCommon
{
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
    //this property makes everything crazy if A inherits from B
}

public A : ABCommon
{
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

It's just a simple 1-to-many relationship between A and B.